# Load legacy sqlite3 db into postgresql on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql

I have an sqlite3 database with data I want to load into my Heroku app's postgres db.

What's the best way to do this?

I was going to try exporting the records (it's a single table) to a yaml file and then uploading that file to heroku and initializing new records from it, but I ran into encoding issues. Those problems aside, is that a good approach? What's a better way of solving that problem?

Answer (score 2):

A good way to transfer data to a different type of database is to use the [yaml_db gem](https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db). After adding it to your Gemfile and running bundle, you can then extract the data locally using:

```
rake db:data:dump
```

This will produce a db/data.yml file. Check this into Git, push to Heroku, then run:

```
heroku run console
rake db:data:load
```

That should do it.